# "Class has two properties of the same name" error when converting an XML file into a Java object

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have an XML file like below, and I want to convert it into a Java object.

```
<P1>
    <CTS>
        Hello
    </CTS>
    <CTS>
        World
    </CTS>
<P1>
```

So I created the following Java classes with their properties.

P1 class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class P1 {
    @XmlElement(name = "CTS")
    List<CTS> cts;
}
```

CTS class

```
public class CTS {
    String ct;
}
```

Test Class

```
File file = new File("D:\\ContentTemp.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(P1.class);
     
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            P1 p = (P1) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

But I am getting the following error:

> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException:
> 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
> Class has two properties of the same name "cts"

Comment: You need to put package-info.java in your generated jaxb package.

Comment: @Festus I am not getting your point. Can you please explain.

Comment: you may want to use <P1>
 <CTSELEMENTS>
     <CTS>
         Hello
     </CTS>
     <CTS>
         World
     </CTS>
  </CTSELEMENTS>
<P1> better to wrap group of same elements in a wrapper.

Comment: Normally you have to create a xml schemata that generates automatically the java objects for you. until you want to do it manually you have to create package-info.java by yourselves

Comment: @Senthil Kumar  Doesn't P1 acts as a wrapper.?

Comment: it would but you declared P1 as XMLRootELement. I would have done like P1 as XMLRootElement, CTSWrapper as XMLELementWrapper, CTS as XMLElement. This way i have never faced issues with marshalling/unmarshalling and works good with json (jackson) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException:
> 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
> Class has two properties of the same name "cts"

By default a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation creates mappings based on properties and annotated fields.  When you annotate a field for which there is also a property it will cause this error.

You have two options:

1. **Use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`**

   You could annotate the field you need to specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on the class.

   ```java
   @XmlRootElement(name="P1)
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   public class P1 {

       @XmlElement(name = "CTS")
       List<CTS> cts;

   }
   ```
2. Option #2 - Annotate the Property (get method)**

   Alternatively you could annotate the `get` method.

   ```java
   @XmlRootElement(name="P1)
   public class P1 {

       List<CTS> cts;

       @XmlElement(name = "CTS")
       public List<CTS> getCts() {
           return cts;
       }

   }
   ```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

---

**FULL EXAMPLE**

**CTS**

You can use the `@XmlValue` annotation to map to Java class to a complex type with simple content.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CTS {

    @XmlValue
    String ct;

}
```

**P1**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="P1")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class P1 {

    @XmlElement(name = "CTS")
    List<CTS> cts;

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(P1.class);
        
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum13987708/input.xml");
        P1 p1 = (P1) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
        
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(p1, System.out);
    }
    
}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<P1>
    <CTS>
        Hello
    </CTS>
    <CTS>
        World
    </CTS>
</P1>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I can see:

1) You need to use `P1.class` in your `JAXBContext`. You haven't said what the `Presentation` class is, but if your root element is `P1`, that's what you need in the context:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(P1.class);
```

2) You need to specify the name of the root xml element:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="P1")
public class P1 {
...
```

Comment: this is right . I have changed the variable name .forgot to change it in test class.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error because you haven't posted all the code. Do you have a method called `cts()` as well? If so, try renaming it to something else.

Comment: no.this is whole my code. There is only getter and setters other than this code. The error showing is because it has two cts in xml file

Comment: no, I have run the code you posted and it works for me. According to the error, you have two properties called `cts` in the class. It doesn't have anything to do with your xml.

Comment: code run without error in your system?

Comment: yes, I do not get any errors. Have you tried running the code you posted in the question?

Comment: Yes. It is not working. Is there is any jar neeeded. Let me give this code to my friend and see it works.

Comment: why do you have `@XmlElement(name = "CT")` in the CTS class? What is CT?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML looks like this:

```xml
<P1>
  <CTS>
    Hello
  </CTS>
  <CTS>
    World
  </CTS>
</P1>
```

But considering your mapping it should look like:

```xml
<p1>
  <CTS>
    <CT>
    Hello
    </CT>
  </CTS>
  <CTS>
    <CT>
    World
    </CT>
  </CTS>
</p1>
```

In order to change root element from p1 to P1 use attribute `name` from `@XmlRootElement`.

If you want to parse the first version of XML you posted, change your P1 class like this:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="P1")
public class P1 {
    @XmlElement(name = "CTS")
    List<String> cts;
 }
```

Comment: FYI - You can map the object model to the XML given by @Thinker by leveraging the `@XmlValue` annotation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13988362/383861

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following,

If you could, make xml as of the following structure.

```
<P1>
    <CTSList>
       <CTS value="Hello"/>
       <CTS value="World"/>
    </CTSList>
<P1>
```

And use,

```
@XMLRootElement(name="P1")
public class P1 {
  List CTSList;

  @XMLElementWrapper(name="CTSList")
  @XMLELement(name="CTS")
  public void setCTSList(List<CTS> ctsList) {
     this.CTSList = ctsList;
  }

  public List<CTS> getCTSList() {
    return this.CTSList;
  }
}

@XMLRootElement(name="CTS")
public class CTS {
   String cts;

   @XMLAttribute(name = "value")
   public String getCts() {
     return this.cts;
   }

   public void set setCts(String cts) {
     this.cts = cts;
   }
}
```

Comment: FYI - You can map the object model to the XML given by @Thinker by leveraging the `@XmlValue` annotation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13988362/383861